# ServletContextListener called twice for one virtual host on glassfish

Tags: glassfish, servletcontextlistener

I have a situation when ServletContextListener methods contextInitialized is called twice even if I have only one virtual host defined on the server ... I use Glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue I faced recently with glassfish where I had my `ServletContextListener` invoked twice even if I had a single virtual host defined on the glassfish server 
By far I found three reasons why this can happen, and they are as follows

1. If we configure `servlet` with `web.xml` and `servlet annotation` at the same time
2. If we have multiple virual host on application server(Which doesn't stand valid for this question as we have only one virtual host)
3. If the application is already deployed on glassfish server and when you run the servlet, the application server starts the servlet which is already and then redeploys the servlet which we asked it to run . so turns out the listener is called twice

Now if we start the glassfish server with no application deployed on it and then run the servlet the method is only called once.

I hope this helped